# How to write pretty URL based from data?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to write pretty url from these data?
I need something like this https://mywebsite.com/admin/leads/count/data1/data2/data3

Thanks in advance. :)

```js
var x = {data1, data2, data3};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://mywebsite.com/admin/leads/count/',
  data: x,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
      $("#leads_count").val(data);
      leadsCtr = data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take url as a string and manipulate it like this

```
    var x = {data1, data2, data3};
    var string = 'https://mywebsite.com/admin/leads/count/';
    var fstring = string+x.data1+'/'+x.data2+'/'+x.data3;
    $.ajax({
    url: fstring,
    data: x,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
  $("#leads_count").val(data);
  leadsCtr = data;
}
```

});

Comment: Hi @EpicAdidash thank you for your answer but unable to get the last value or the data3. Thanks for your help sir.

Comment: Got it. It's because there's # in my URL. Will just trim it anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).